# Windows explorer vs Mac Finder, which is better for navigating folder hierarchy?

Tags: hierarchy

[image]
[image]

What are the guiding design principles behind the two different methods of navigating the folder?

Answer (score 0):

I'am Windows user and must admit that MacOS Finder is better.

1. It's overloaded by default (too noisy). Too many unnecessary elements i.e. i don't need 3D Objects, OneDrive and unable to remove it without hacks.
2. View modes: Finder provides convenient way to switch view modes. Explorer has 8 modes burried inside menus.
3. Explorer has too narrow columns by default (legacy from age with 1024x768 screens). I'm sure that it's possible to auto-adjust column width by OS.